# Is anything else added to the original context except $ and jQuery using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I know, $ and jQuery are added to the global context when we use jQuery.

Is anything else added, like document property or event?

Comment: Just curious, why do you ask?

Comment: if you have some time, you can check it out for yourself http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Wrong answer</s>

The only two things that seem to extend outside the `()()`; definition of jQuery are

```
~Line 24:    jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = 

~Line 2425:  window.Sizzle = Sizzle;
```

Actually, window.Sizzle is defined in 1.3.2 but not in 1.5 (at least).  Just open up your jQuery.js file, then do a whole-word search for `"window."` (less quotes).  There shouldn't be many.  Only adding them to `window.` are they persisted outside the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

> The jQuery library, and virtually all of its plugins are constrained within the jQuery namespace. As a general rule, "global" objects are stored inside the jQuery namespace as well, so you shouldn't get a clash between jQuery and any other library (like Prototype, MooTools, or YUI).
>
> That said, there is one caveat: By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

So, unless you are using a plugin that defines something in the global namespace, you should only have to worry about `jQuery` and `$`.  See the reference for how to avoid conflicts with other libraries that may also define the `$` function.

Answer (score 1):

No.  jQuery and $ are the only thing added at a global level:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

You can use a tool like Firebug to confirm what has been added to window.